# Syntax of nested if openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I can't find a place that explains me how can i do the code bellow (c# example) in a view of openerp.

```
IF(type != 'out_refund' AND (state == "open" OR !sent)){
   «print»
}
```

At the moment i have this code but its not working:

```
<button name="invoice_pay_customer" type="object" string="Register Payment" 
attrs="{'invisible': ['&',('type','=','out_refund'),'|', ('state','!=','open'), ('sent','=',True) ] }" 
groups="base.group_user"/>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):
~(A and B) = ~A or ~B
~(A or B) = ~A and ~B

If B=(C or ~D) and A to be ~A, then:
~A and (C or ~D) when you want to see it, so when you don't want to see it is:
~(~A and (C or ~D)) = A or ~(C or ~D) = ***A or (~C and D)***
Now, you have to transform it to [polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation): **OR A (AND ~CD)**

A: type == 'out_refund'
B: state == "open"
C: sent == True

*Note: in XML, you need to use `&amp;` in place of `&`. This will be work on openERP.
I assumed `type` and `state` and `sent` is a field, in other case this won't work.*

```
attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('type','=','out_refund'), '&amp;', ('state','!=','open'), ('sent','=',True) ] }"
```

Comment: My problem was the «&amp» notation, I've always assumed the & on code. 
Another thing, type, state, and sent must be in quotes: 'type','=','out_refund'.
Thank you.